# Cantonese characters in LaTeX (Ubuntu)

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode

I'm trying to type the characters 部機都冇咗嘞。in a LaTeX document, but I've never done it before (this sentence can be found in sentence #9 in this [Universal Dependencies Github repository](https://github.com/UniversalDependencies/UD_Cantonese-HK/blob/master/yue_hk-ud-test.conllu)). I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
部機都冇咗嘞。
\end{document}
```

does not work (neither `pdflatex file.tex`, `xelatex file.tex` nor `lualatex file.tex`). [This option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575521/202783) does not work for me either since it proposes using a font by Microsoft, and I'm working on Ubuntu (if anyone knows how to install that font, please help! ;) ).

The errors I get are:

- `pdflatex file.tex`:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 部 (U+90E8)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

- `xelatex file.tex`: no errors, but blank output. Warnings:

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

- `lualatex file.tex`: no errors, but blank output. Warnings:

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

Could someone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: the important warnings are in the log not on the terminal, search for "missing character" it will tell you that latin modern font does not have those characters,

Comment: Ok, will do the next time! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\cjkfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}

{\cjkfont  部機都冇咗嘞}

\end{document}
```

That runs with lualatex or xelatex on ubuntu but the fourth and fifth characters are not in the font so you get

[image]

But if you have a font that works for those character just substitute it in

If you have Noto Sans CJK TC font installed that has more complete coverage:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @David! Quite interestingly, my browser and Geany (the text editor I use to write LaTeX) do display those characters... This means there is a font in my computer programs can use to display those characters. Is there any option to tell LaTeX to use those fonts?

Comment: yes sure any font your browser uses you can use in xelatex, also noto sans cjk works, this is running on ubuntu: https://texlive.net/run?%25%20!TEX%20xelatex%0A%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bfontspec%7D%0A%5Csetmainfont%7Btexgyretermes-regular.otf%7D%0A%5Cnewfontfamily%5Ccjkfont%7BNoto%20Sans%20CJK%20KR%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%0A%7B%5Ccjkfont%20%20%E9%83%A8%E6%A9%9F%E9%83%BD%E5%86%87%E5%92%97%E5%98%9E%7D%0A%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D

Comment: in the browser you can use the inspect menu to see what font it is using and use the same here, the details depend on the browser you are using

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Noto Serif CJK TC includes traditional Chinese characters (those used in Cantonese). If in TL, it will work with a full TL distribution

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wow, your second comment just made everything so much better. I really wondered what fonts were being used and was about to ask you. But you told me without me having to ask! Nice link in your first comment. Thank you, really :)

Comment: @JairoA.delRio yes thanks I have the KR version installed at texlive.net as someone was working on a Korean translation but as you say TC would be better, actually I have Noto Sans CJK TC installed that looks like https://texlive.net/run?%25%20!TEX%20xelatex%0A%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bfontspec%7D%0A%5Csetmainfont%7Btexgyretermes-regular.otf%7D%0A%5Cnewfontfamily%5Ccjkfont%7BNoto%20Sans%20CJK%20TC%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%0A%7B%5Ccjkfont%20%20%E9%83%A8%E6%A9%9F%E9%83%BD%E5%86%87%E5%92%97%E5%98%9E%7D%0A%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D